# Outlook VSTO Add-in not visible in Outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook Add-in(under development) which was working fine on my old system. I decided to migrate to a new system(for better performance), when I have done so(IN DEBUG MODE), I saw that after some time the Add-in is not visible in Outlook(neither in COM AND disabled window).

**Specifications I am using:**

- System type is 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5 with .NET framework 4.7.2
- Microsoft Office 365(16.012730.20144) 32-bit

**Troubleshoots I tried:**

1) Checked [Build Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/building-office-solutions?view=vs-2019), for verifying all items are generating and working properly.

- Registry entry is generating correctly.
- VSTO file(bin/debug) is getting installed successfully(when I manually double click that)

2) Troubleshooting by Event Viewer:

No error's related to Outlook(as a source).

Possibly related error's:

i) Source - DistributedCOM : The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}
 and APPID 
{4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

ii) Other Errors are from source PerfNet and NDIS(Which I suppose is not related to this topic)

3) Troubleshooting by Process Explorer:

Their is no outlook Add-in DLL present in process explorer.

4) Troubleshooting by Process Monitor:

I am new with procmon, so just used some basics like, applied a filter with Outlook process name(including registry, file system, Network, process and thread activities).
And the results were SUCCESS, BUFFER TOO SMALL, NAME NOT FOUND, NO MORE ENTERIES other. Their was nothing I can relate with my issue.

**Other Information**

- After this issue, I made a same new project and it worked fine, but the same happened(Add-in not visible) after some time. And I have done this(Created new project) four times till now. What I observed is, when I create a new Add-in with same name, the issue is same, so I have to choose different name every-time.

I am not able to find any error description for this. So can anybody please tell me what is the issue here OR how I can troubleshoot more(with above tools or new one).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see your add-in listed in the COM add-ins dialog of Office applications, the problem is related to Windows registry keys required. Read more about them in the [Registry entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) article.

It seems something is wrong with your add-in registry entries (maybe permissions). And the issue can be related to Windows/Office bitness. Most probably you had another Office edition (bitness) installed on the old system (or Windows).

Comment: Thanks, you were correct. The issue was with both Windows/Office bitness and registry key. Actually, my OS is of 64 bit and office installed is of 32 bit, which requires registry entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Wow6432Node\microsoft\office\Outlook\Addins. So I added registry at above location manually (as same for Current user), and now the Addin is visible in Outlook.
But I am still wondering that if the registry entry was not present that how the addin was visible for some time in outlook?
Also, how I can make these changes in both VS debug mode and Windows installer project?

Comment: Using Office 2019 I got a similar problem from the question! An interesting observation: at startup Outlook 2019, the Add-In is disabled with an error, but if it is forcibly enabled, it will fall into the "inactive add-in's" section with the status "compatibility: no compatibility information". Question - how to specify compatibility in the project?

Comment: My add-on creates keys in the registry automatically according to the instructions [Register VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019#deployment-type) Deleted my keys. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\xxx`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\xxx` Restarted Outlook 2019, it's working. Microsoft, what's going on? Was there something wrong with the permissions on the registry branches?